# How do I make this code to produce a result in a reasonable time

Tags: java

I am developing a class to guess a secret key. The secret key containing 16 random letters of "t" "r" "m" "i". But the run time is taking too long to produce. The goal is to produce the lowest guess count, in this case, if the code were to produce actual result, it will only take 4 guesses. Here is the code for the 2 classes "secretkey" and the one I am working on it "secretkeyguesser":
package project;

```
public class SecretKey {
    private String correctKey;
    private int counter;

    public SecretKey() {
        // for the real test, your program will not know this
        correctKey = "RRRRRRRRRMITRMIT";
        counter = 0;
    }

    public int guess(String guessedKey) {
        counter++;
        // validation
        if (guessedKey.length() != correctKey.length()) {
            return -1;
        }
        int matched = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < guessedKey.length(); i++) {
            char c = guessedKey.charAt(i);
            if (c != 'R' && c != 'M' && c != 'I' && c != 'T') {
                return -1;
            }
            if (c == correctKey.charAt(i)) {
                matched++;
            }
        }
        if (matched == correctKey.length()) {
            System.out.println("Number of guesses: " + counter);
        }
        return matched;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SecretKeyGuesser().start();
    }
}
```

```
package project;

public class SecretKeyGuesser {
    public void start() {
        // generate keys
        String key1 = "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR";
        String key2 = "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM";
        String key3 = "IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII";
        String key4 = "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT";

        // initialize correct positions
        int[] correct1 = new int[16];
        int[] correct2 = new int[16];
        int[] correct3 = new int[16];
        int[] correct4 = new int[16];

        SecretKey key = new SecretKey();
        String guess = "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR";
        int numCorrect = key.guess(guess);

        while (numCorrect != 16) {
            // update correct positions for each key
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                char c = guess.charAt(i);
                if (c == 'R') {
                    correct1[i] += 1;
                } else if (c == 'M') {
                    correct2[i] += 1;
                } else if (c == 'I') {
                    correct3[i] += 1;
                } else {
                    correct4[i] += 1;
                }
            }

            // generate next guess
            guess = nextGuess(correct1, correct2, correct3, correct4);
            numCorrect = key.guess(guess);
        }

        // merge keys based on correct positions
        StringBuilder secretKey = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (correct1[i] == 1) {
                secretKey.append(guess.charAt(i));
            } else if (correct2[i] == 1) {
                secretKey.append(guess.charAt(i));
            } else if (correct3[i] == 1) {
                secretKey.append(guess.charAt(i));
            } else {
                secretKey.append(guess.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("I found the secret key. It is " + secretKey.toString());
    }

    // return the next guess based on correct positions
    public String nextGuess(int[] correct1, int[] correct2, int[] correct3, int[] correct4) {
        StringBuilder nextGuess = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (correct1[i] == 0) {
                nextGuess.append('R');
            } else if (correct2[i] == 0) {
                nextGuess.append('M');
            } else if (correct3[i] == 0) {
                nextGuess.append('I');
            } else {
                nextGuess.append('T');
            }
        }
        return nextGuess.toString();
    }
}
```

what was trying to do in the secretkeyguesser class is to scan for the correct index position for each of 4 letters and then once having all of the correct position, put them all in a string.

Comment: Does the code work in general? Then it might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don’t see how the code as shown can possibly work.  For example, each call to `guess` returns the `numCorrect` variable, but that result is totally ignored for making the future guesses !!    In fact, whatever the result of the First guess (even 0 ! ), the code immediately goes into ` // update correct positions for each key` and will simply repeat the guess - In fact I don’t see how your guesses are ever going to change !

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is too inefficient, as you only know the number of correct chars, but not which one are correct. I would use an approach rather like this:

```
public void start() {
    // generate keys
    SecretKey key = new SecretKey();

    // rather start from an all-wrong key, then you don't have to look which are already correct
    String guess = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    char[] chars = guess.toCharArray();
    int numCorrect = 0;
    int newNumCorrect = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 16 && numCorrect != 16) {
        while (newNumCorrect == numCorrect) {
            chars[i] = switch (chars[i]) {
                case 'R' -> 'M';
                case 'M' -> 'I';
                case 'I' -> 'T';
                default -> 'R';
            };
            guess = String.copyValueOf(chars);
            //System.out.println(guess);
            newNumCorrect = key.guess(guess);
        }
        numCorrect = newNumCorrect;
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("I found the secret key. It is " + String.copyValueOf(chars));
}
```

By this, even in the worst case the program only needs 64 (=16*4) guesses, and runs in under one second. You only have to comment / delete `if (c != 'R' && c != 'M' && c != 'I' && c != 'T') {return -1;}` in the SecretKey.java file, it isn't necessary anyway.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying. I will take a look of the code and share with you any updates.

Comment: Hi, the run time is taking too long to actual produce  an answer. Have to try and run it?